# Give filename for zip.js to compress

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression, zip, download

I am using [Zip.js][1] to compress files and make them ready to download, the [example][2] here shows how to do it using `input type="file" multiple id="file-input"` and get files from `file-input.file` and works fine. But in my case I have the code below on my page and I want to compress and download all the files by sending the information, i have href of the individual download links. Note that all the files are on the server. It will be nice if there is any way I can do this using only javascript? Thank you!!

```
    <a href="files/pdffile.pdf">Download PDF File</a><br />
    <a href="files/image.png">Download Image</a><br />
    <a href="files/word.doc">Download Word File</a><br />
    <a href="files/test.txt">Download Text File</a><br />

    <span class="label">set zip file name</span>
    <input type="text" id="filename-input" value="Example.zip">
    <span class="label">download the zip file</span>
    <a id="download-button" href="#">Download</a>
```

[Link1](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js) and
[Link2](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html)